# If $p(A,B,C,D) = p(A,B) \cdot p(C,D)$, then is $p(A \mid B,C,D) = p(A \mid B)$?

Tags: independence, conditional-independence

Given the discrete random variables $A,B,C,$ and $D$, if
$$
p(A = a,B = b,C = c,D = d) = p(A = a,B = b) \cdot  p(C = c,D = d) \ \forall a,b,c,d
$$
then is
$$
p(A = a \mid B = b,C = c,D = d) = p(A = a \mid B = b)
$$
and
$$
p(B = b \mid A = a,C = c,D = d) = p(B = b \mid A = a)
$$
for all $a,b,c,$ and $d$?

Comment: The general principle is that when writing conditional probabilities, you don't explicitly have to condition on every other variable in the universe that is independent of the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
p(A = a \mid B = b,C = c,D = d) &= \frac{p(A = a,B = b,C = c,D = d)}{\sum_{a} p(A = a,B = b,C = c,D = d)} \\
&= \frac{p(A = a,B = b) \cdot p(C = c,D = d)}{\sum_{a} p(A = a,B = b) \cdot p(C = c,D = d)} \\
&= \frac{p(A = a,B = b) \cdot p(C = c,D = d)}{p(C = c,D = d) \cdot p(B = b)} \\
&= \frac{p(A = a,B = b)}{p(B = b)} \\
&= p(A = a \mid B = b)
\end{align}
The proof for
$$
p(B = b \mid A = a,C = c,D = d) = p(B = b \mid A = a)
$$
follows in a similar way.